# Why is my CSS3 animation not working in Chrome or Safari?

Tags: css, translate-animation

I'm using a `translate` animation, but it doesn't work in Safari or Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code, [and a JSFiddle of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/prologo/MLhYS/2/):

#### HTML

```
<div id="animate"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-animation:move 6s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation:move 6s ease infinite;
  animation: move 6s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and when I looked at the fiddle it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Webkit still needs the `-webkit` prefix for `transform`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
   50% {
     -webkit-transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MLhYS/3/**