# Why does my CSS Animation not work in Safari 12?

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, css-transforms

The title basically gives it away. I have an animation working just fine in Chrome (80) and Firefox (57), but does not work in Safari (12) at all.

What I expect to happen is a straight line is drawn across the screen diagonally, from left top to right bottom.

I've tried a dozen variations of my code, the following is one:
(all the variations I tried work perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox)

```
    #move {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: mymove;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--a));
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: mymove;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-transform: rotate(var(--a));
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-animation-name: mymove;
    -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-transform: rotate(var(--a));
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-name: mymove;
    -o-animation-duration: 3s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-transform: rotate(var(--a));
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-name: mymove;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform: rotate(var(--a));
    transform-origin: top left;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }



@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    to {
    width: var(--w);
    /*background-color: rgb(67, 67, 92);*/
    }
    }

@-moz-keyframes mymove {
to {
width: var(--w);
/*background-color: rgb(67, 67, 92);*/
}
}

@-ms-keyframes mymove {
to {
width: var(--w);
/*background-color: rgb(67, 67, 92);*/
}
}

@-o-keyframes mymove {
    to {
    width: var(--w);
    /*background-color: rgb(67, 67, 92);*/
    }
    }

@keyframes mymove {
    to {
    width: var(--w);
    /*background-color: rgb(67, 67, 92);*/
    }
    }
```

a shorter one:

```
#move {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  animation: mymove 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(var(--a));

}

@keyframes mymove {
    to {
    width: var(--w);
    }
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="move"></div>
```

I tried to consider:

webkit:
[Why is my CSS3 animation not working in Chrome or Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355235/why-is-my-css3-animation-not-working-in-chrome-or-safari)

[CSS3 animation: Not loading in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258359/css3-animation-not-loading-in-safari)

[Transform: rotate doesn't work in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316184/transform-rotate-doesnt-work-in-safari)

Splitting up the shorthand notation:
[CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

Delaying the animation:
[CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

None of what I tried seem to work in Safari. What am I missing here? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: in the first snippet, you dont have a @keyframes statement, only webkit. In the second, the @ is missing

Comment: even with added @keyframes statement in the first snippet it does not work. The missing @ (in the second snippet) was simply a copying mistake, it still does not work. Does any of the code work for you using Safari?

Comment: Sorry, I can not test in Safari. I was just looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Like the OP, I was setting up the keyframe using the 'to' property:

```
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    dash-offset: 0;
  }
}
```

This seems to be fine with Chrome and Firefox. I discovered that Safari and iOS Safari require the 'from' property to be set as well. This is contrary to [MDN's claim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) that 'If a keyframe rule doesn't specify the start or end states of the animation (that is, 0%/from and 100%/to), browsers will use the element's existing styles for the start/end states.'

I was animating a dynamic element, so I ended up using the Web Animations API to describe an animation that all browsers could understand:

```
const lineAnimationTiming: EffectTiming = {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'ease-in-out'
    };
const length = line.getTotalLength();
line.style.strokeDasharray = `${length} ${length}`;
line.animate(
  [
    { strokeDashoffset: length },
    { strokeDashoffset: 0 }
  ],
  lineAnimationTiming
);
```

EDIT Sep 3, 2021:
Testing Safari using vanilla HTML/Javascript/CSS, this issue does not reproduce. See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vmalvc?file=styles.css).
I happened to be using Angular when I first encountered the issue. This issue does reproduce there. See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9nih37?file=src%2Fstyles.css). Reported to Angular as [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43335).